# Entangled Photons Emited from Stars

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-entanglement

Do starts emit entangled photons? If so, how do you calculate the percentage of photons that are entangled?

What are the mechanisms that would cause a star to emit entangled photons?

Comment: +1 thanks for rephrasing my question. what are the requirements for the emission of entangled photons?

Comment: Wow, quite a coincidence. Are you also trying to find a fundamental limit on the power of a quantum computer?

Comment: we must have had entangled thoughts